# Change marker width and height in scatter chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I need to change marker width and height in scatter chart. Now i have this chart:
[image: Current version]

I need to customize markers size, depending on some data. But there is only one property radius for them. Marker can be circular or angular.

[image: Proposed version]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.marker.symbol)?

Comment: There is not a built-in option for changing the width and height of a marker independently - only the radius in general. You would have to do it yourself - search for how to extend the marker function to draw your own, and allow inputs of height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. For each series i can set marker property. And inside it i can set icon and size of marker. Here is example of series:

```
{
        name: 'Female',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        marker: {
                symbol: 'circle',
                width: 16,
                height: 16
            },
        data: [[161.2, 51.6], [167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
            [170.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6], [166.0, 69.8], [176.2, 66.8], [160.2, 75.2],
            [172.5, 55.2], [170.9, 54.2], [172.9, 62.5], [153.4, 42.0], [160.0, 50.0],
            [147.2, 49.8], [168.2, 49.2], [175.0, 73.2], [157.0, 47.8], [167.6, 68.8],
            [159.5, 50.6], [175.0, 82.5], [166.8, 57.2], [176.5, 87.8], [170.2, 72.8],
            [174.0, 54.5], [173.0, 59.8], [179.9, 67.3], [170.5, 67.8], [160.0, 47.0],
            [154.4, 46.2], [162.0, 55.0], [176.5, 83.0], [160.0, 54.4], [152.0, 45.8],
            [162.1, 53.6], [170.0, 73.2], [160.2, 52.1], [161.3, 67.9], [166.4, 56.6],
            [168.9, 62.3], [163.8, 58.5], [167.6, 54.5], [160.0, 50.2], [161.3, 60.3],
            [167.6, 58.3], [165.1, 56.2], [160.0, 50.2], [170.0, 72.9], [157.5, 59.8],
            [167.6, 61.0], [160.7, 69.1], [163.2, 55.9], [152.4, 46.5], [157.5, 54.3],
            [168.3, 54.8], [180.3, 60.7], [165.5, 60.0], [165.0, 62.0], [164.5, 60.3],
            [156.0, 52.7], [160.0, 74.3], [163.0, 62.0], [165.7, 73.1], [161.0, 80.0],
            [162.0, 54.7], [166.0, 53.2], [174.0, 75.7], [172.7, 61.1], [167.6, 55.7],
            [151.1, 48.7], [164.5, 52.3], [163.5, 50.0], [152.0, 59.3], [169.0, 62.5],
            [164.0, 55.7], [161.2, 54.8], [155.0, 45.9], [170.0, 70.6], [176.2, 67.2],
            [170.0, 69.4], [162.5, 58.2], [170.3, 64.8], [164.1, 71.6], [169.5, 52.8],
            [163.2, 59.8], [154.5, 49.0], [159.8, 50.0], [173.2, 69.2], [170.0, 55.9],
            [161.4, 63.4], [169.0, 58.2], [166.2, 58.6], [159.4, 45.7], [162.5, 52.2],
            [159.0, 48.6], [162.8, 57.8], [159.0, 55.6], [179.8, 66.8], [162.9, 59.4],
            [161.0, 53.6], [151.1, 73.2], [168.2, 53.4], [168.9, 69.0], [173.2, 58.4],
            [171.8, 56.2], [178.0, 70.6], [164.3, 59.8], [163.0, 72.0], [168.5, 65.2],
            [166.8, 56.6], [172.7, 105.2], [163.5, 51.8], [169.4, 63.4], [167.8, 59.0],
            [159.5, 47.6], [167.6, 63.0], [161.2, 55.2], [160.0, 45.0], [163.2, 54.0],
            [162.2, 50.2], [161.3, 60.2], [149.5, 44.8], [157.5, 58.8], [163.2, 56.4],
            [172.7, 62.0], [155.0, 49.2], [156.5, 67.2], [164.0, 53.8], [160.9, 54.4],
            [162.8, 58.0], [167.0, 59.8], [160.0, 54.8], [160.0, 43.2], [168.9, 60.5],
            [158.2, 46.4], [156.0, 64.4], [160.0, 48.8], [167.1, 62.2], [158.0, 55.5],
            [167.6, 57.8], [156.0, 54.6], [162.1, 59.2], [173.4, 52.7], [159.8, 53.2],
            [170.5, 64.5], [159.2, 51.8], [157.5, 56.0], [161.3, 63.6], [162.6, 63.2],
            [160.0, 59.5], [168.9, 56.8], [165.1, 64.1], [162.6, 50.0], [165.1, 72.3],
            [166.4, 55.0], [160.0, 55.9], [152.4, 60.4], [170.2, 69.1], [162.6, 84.5],
            [170.2, 55.9], [158.8, 55.5], [172.7, 69.5], [167.6, 76.4], [162.6, 61.4],
            [167.6, 65.9], [156.2, 58.6], [175.2, 66.8], [172.1, 56.6], [162.6, 58.6],
            [160.0, 55.9], [165.1, 59.1], [182.9, 81.8], [166.4, 70.7], [165.1, 56.8],
            [177.8, 60.0], [165.1, 58.2], [175.3, 72.7], [154.9, 54.1], [158.8, 49.1],
            [172.7, 75.9], [168.9, 55.0], [161.3, 57.3], [167.6, 55.0], [165.1, 65.5],
            [175.3, 65.5], [157.5, 48.6], [163.8, 58.6], [167.6, 63.6], [165.1, 55.2],
            [165.1, 62.7], [168.9, 56.6], [162.6, 53.9], [164.5, 63.2], [176.5, 73.6],
            [168.9, 62.0], [175.3, 63.6], [159.4, 53.2], [160.0, 53.4], [170.2, 55.0],
            [162.6, 70.5], [167.6, 54.5], [162.6, 54.5], [160.7, 55.9], [160.0, 59.0],
            [157.5, 63.6], [162.6, 54.5], [152.4, 47.3], [170.2, 67.7], [165.1, 80.9],
            [172.7, 70.5], [165.1, 60.9], [170.2, 63.6], [170.2, 54.5], [170.2, 59.1],
            [161.3, 70.5], [167.6, 52.7], [167.6, 62.7], [165.1, 86.3], [162.6, 66.4],
            [152.4, 67.3], [168.9, 63.0], [170.2, 73.6], [175.2, 62.3], [175.2, 57.7],
            [160.0, 55.4], [165.1, 104.1], [174.0, 55.5], [170.2, 77.3], [160.0, 80.5],
            [167.6, 64.5], [167.6, 72.3], [167.6, 61.4], [154.9, 58.2], [162.6, 81.8],
            [175.3, 63.6], [171.4, 53.4], [157.5, 54.5], [165.1, 53.6], [160.0, 60.0],
            [174.0, 73.6], [162.6, 61.4], [174.0, 55.5], [162.6, 63.6], [161.3, 60.9],
            [156.2, 60.0], [149.9, 46.8], [169.5, 57.3], [160.0, 64.1], [175.3, 63.6],
            [169.5, 67.3], [160.0, 75.5], [172.7, 68.2], [162.6, 61.4], [157.5, 76.8],
            [176.5, 71.8], [164.4, 55.5], [160.7, 48.6], [174.0, 66.4], [163.8, 67.3]]

    }
```